# Having trouble with passing data from one ViewController to the next

Tags: swift, viewcontroller

I'm learning swift from couple months and one thing I keep screwing up is passing data between ViewControllers.  When I PO the path of the forward looking variable from within the `prepareForSegue` method, the value is intact.  But when the new ViewController actually appears and I checked its value, it is nil at that point. if anyone could point me in the right direction I'd be very appreciative.

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

var user_ID:String = ""

//this below is within another method activated by button
  Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print ("there was an error signing in")
            print (error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        else {
            //go to home screen
            let userUID = result?.user.uid
            print (userUID)
            self.user_ID = userUID
            
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "MainSegue", sender: self)
        }
    

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    
    //this is the destination VC
    let viewController = segue.destination as! ViewController
        
    viewController.user_ID = self.user_ID
    
    //NOTE: if I break here and PO viewConroller.user_ID the value is intact

    let homeViewController = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainVC"))! as! ViewController
             
                //let mainViewController = ViewController()
                //mainViewController.user_ID = userUID
                                  
    self.present(homeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
   
}








class ViewController: UIViewController {

var persons = [Person]()
let db = Firestore.firestore()

 var user_ID:String = ""

 //NOTE: WHEN `viewdidload` runs value of user_ID is nil
```

Comment: self.user_ID , where did you initialize the user_ID ?

Comment: I have declared :   var user_ID:String = "" in each the LoginViewController (originating VC) and in the ViewController class (destination)

Comment: Don't create and present a 2nd view controller.  Let the segue put up the one in `destination`.  You are setting the data in one instance and then presenting a different one.

Comment: Thank you Phillip!!! you are exactly right, that worked like a charm.  :). you are a genius!!!

Answer (score -1):

Phillip in the comments above provided the solution.  The present ViewController was the problem. The segue already does that. Thank you!!!